# Determinant of covariance and correlation matrix

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, entropy

I am reading the book Network Information Theory by El Gamal and I can't understand this particular part given in the book:

Let $X \sim f(x^n)$ be a random vector with co-variance matrix $K_X = E[(X − E(X))(X − E(X))^T] \geq 0$. Then $$h(X) \leq \frac{1}{2}\log ((2\pi e)^n|K_X|) \leq \frac{1}{2}\log((2\pi e)^n|E(XX^T)|)$$

where $E(XX^T)$ is the correlation matrix of $X$. The first inequality holds with equality
if and only if X is Gaussian and the second inequality holds with equality if and only if
$E(X) = 0$.

I can't understand how the author introduced the 2nd inequality with the correlation matrix. Is there any result that determinant of correlation matrix is always greater than equal to determinant of co-variance matrix?

Comment: Note $E(XX^T)=K_X+(EX)(EX)^T$, so $K_X\prec E(XX^T)$. To call $E(XX^T)$ the "correlation" is weird.

Comment: @kimchilover what does that inequality prove? Based on my understanding, what you wrote means $E(XX^T)-K_X)$ is positive definite, but how does that help wrt the determinants of the individual matrices?

Comment: Yes.  For psd matrices, $A\prec B$ means, intuitively, that the eigenvalues of $A$ are smaller than those of $B$, and so is their product.